# How to concatenate two vectors (by columns)

Tags: matrix, vector, concatenation, stata

I use the code below to concatenate two vectors in a same matrix:

```
tab variable if variable <= number, matcell(x)
matrix list x   
mat a = x
mat a = a\x
```

However, Stata concatenates in a same column with this code.

I need to concatenate it in two vectors in a same matrix making a `nx2` matrix.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful please consider accepting it using the check-mark.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `,` instead of `\`:

```
sysuse auto, clear
tabulate foreign, matcell(x)

matrix list x

x[2,1]
    c1
r1  52
r2  22

matrix a = x
matrix a = a , x

matrix list a

a[2,2]
    c1  c1
r1  52  52
r2  22  22
```